# Record-setting flights in amateur rocketry

Tags: amateur-rocketry

It appears that amateur groups have launched rockets to space (above the Karman line), but these were flights of commercial (Pegasus) rockets by amateur teams.

What I am interested in is record-setting flights using rockets of amateur design and construction - highest altitude attained, highest velocity attained, longest duration under useful thrust. Has any rocket of amateur design/construction launched from essentially sea-level altitude and made it all the way up to or above the Karman line?

Comment: You can have a look at [Copenhagen Suborbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Suborbitals)

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_rocketry#Notable_events):

> On May 17, 2004, Civilian Space eXploration Team (CSXT) successfully achieved the first officially verified flight of an amateur high-power rocket into space, achieving an altitude of 116 km (72 mi).[7]
>
> Prior to that, the Reaction Research Society on November 23, 1996, launched a solid-fuel rocket, designed by longtime member George Garboden, to an altitude of 80 km (50 mi) from the Black Rock Desert in Nevada.[8]

Third place in this list reached an altitude of [33 km](http://www.hobbyspace.com/Rocketry/Advanced/records.html).